# Views as Stored Procedures in Schema Change script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

I have writing a Change script to update the schema in the Production DB. I have to drop a View and recreate them since one of the column in that view is removed now.

I'm planning to use,

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '<View Definition>';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If any, What are the pitfalls of using this approach ? What are the alternatives that you would suggest ?

I'm having the whole script under a transaction with a Try catch block. So when there is no error the script will be committed else rolled back.I tried to use CREATE VIEW Command as below, but I get error after introduction TRASACTION and TRY-CATCH BLOCKS.This reason why am going for Dynamic SQL statement - EXEC sp_executesql.

The error is "CREATE VIEW MUST BE THE ONLY STATEMENT IN THE BATCH"

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'VwViewName')
BEGIN 
DROP VIEW VwViewName
END

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'VwViewName')
BEGIN 
     CREATE VIEW VwViewName
    <VIEW DEFINITION>
END
```

Comment: why do you want to make use of `dynamic SQL`? why don't you use `drop\create` or `alter` `view`? Keep in mind that the `drop` will drop any grant to the view.

Comment: Actually, am dropping and re-creating. Read that, this is the standard  for making changes in the view in Production DB's. Isn't it so ?

Comment: yes it's quite standard process. but not using `dynamic SQL`.

Comment: So you would suggest normal drop/create instead of Dynamic SQL execute commands ? why so ?

Comment: please see my response below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running schema update, you should comply minimal things like

- make it repeatable
- have it in your versioning system
- and test it in your testing environment before running in production.

In order to make it re-runable it's common practice to check if the object exists and drop it, and then to create it again.

Dynamic SQL will not add any functionality that the `IF` clause has.

For example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'MyView')
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW [MyView]
END
GO
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT [Columns list ]
    FROM [MyTable]
GO
```

The only case that I know which justifies `dynamic SQL` is if you want to preserve `grant` / `deny`, in such case you can use following syntax.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'MyView')
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT 1 AS Dummy'
END
GO
ALTER VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT [Columns list ]
    FROM [MyTable]

go
GRANT ....
```

I wouldn't create a `Dynamic SQL` to fill the few times that I have to repeat the names in any of the scripts below. IMHO the deployment script should be as plain as possible.

Comment: True Am storing it in Version Control and testing multiple times in my test environment.But,I'm not sure I exactly understood what you meant by repeatable ? Because, Change scripts should be run only once in the Production DB. (reference : http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-change-scripts.aspx) Or am I interpreting your wrongly ?

Comment: Also am having the whole scheme script as a transaction with a try catch block. If the schema is succesful it will be committed, else Rolled back. I tried to use CREATE VIEW as plain command, I got an error the details of which am adding above.

Comment: regarding the second comment, you need to add a `GO` just above `CREATE ...`

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't allow me to add `GO`. I get **incorrect syntax near GO** error.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, there is no difference between using `Dynamic SQL` combined with transaction. As for `repeatable` I mean that many times in R&D, Staging, QA, Preproduction or any other environment, these `deployment scripts` usually run many times until  they are stable, i.e. many times SQA find many bugs and features that require changing the script. So instead restoring / regenerating the environment from scratch, is common use to run these scripts many times until they get a basic level of stability.

Comment: @Learner, I see your logic, your `IF NOT EXISTS(..)` became irrelevant, if you couldn't `DROP`, your surrounding `TRY`\`CATCH` will pick it, if you managed to `DROP` it doesn't exists; hence you can just keep the `CREATE VIEW...`

Comment: You have been Super HELPFUL :) Very True,Agreed. Initially I wasn't having idea to include 'try-catch', then stumbled upon the option of using them in the code. Hence retained this code. And, actually to workaround this error(CREATE VIEW Should be the first...) I went for Dynamic-SQL. And it works. Is it fine ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37021/discussion-between-luis-ll-and-learner)